# PHP How to detect if method is being called from public or private scope?

Tags: php, oop

How can you detect if a method is being called from within a public, private or protected scope?

For example ...

```
class Foo {

    public function getPassword(){
        $scope = [??????];
        switch($scope){
            case 'public':
                return "*****";
                break;
            case 'protected': case 'private':
                return "IamPassword";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the class I might need a property that might not be visible for the template engine but accessible by the class.

Comment: I don't know PHP but in languages like Java and C# you cannot know the caller of a function. The only possibility there is is to inspect the calltrace and get it from there, but once you have to resort to these things you've usually got a flaw in the design.

Comment: It's not a good point, Variables scope are Constructive Keys thats control your access to class's attributes and methods, you shall never inspect what scope is, you should only respect it. If you call a private method from outside your class, its throw a Fatal Error, so is unverificable. All you can do is set a public funtion that call a private function once the public function open the gate of the class.

Comment: If this matters to your code, then there's a nasty smell in your design

Comment: I am currently setting up getter and setter methods. Thus it would be possible to request a private variable from the public scope. Was just wondering if there is a way to see if the getter method was being called from the template or inside the class.

Comment: If it should only be called from inside the class, then don't make it public

Comment: In this specific instance I am  using the __get and __set magic methods to do some magic. The exact implementation is way to complicated to get into here. I think you are right about setting the scope correctly. Think I just figured out how to handle this specific type of scenario.

Comment: Thanks, that should work. I came to a similar conclusion for this implementation.

Comment: Why down vote this question? It has not been asked on the forum before as far as i can tell. Perfectly legitimate question, even if it is a bad idea for implementation, it is still important to discuss the subject somewhere for the general knowledge base.

Comment: FWIW, I think there is at least one "plausible" scenario for this question/pattern, and it is: deprecating a protected property, in advance of removing it. Hiding existing properties behind accessor methods is a common pattern, which allows to add in the accessor methods the triggering of deprecation calls. But if a property was protected beforehand, accessor methods would actually increase its visibility, by making it public. Hence the need for the check on caller visibility/scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would strongly recommend you to redesign your code as soon as possible. But nevertheless your question seemed interesting to me that is why you may try this:

```
    $scopeIsInner = false;
    $exception = new Exception();
    $trace = $exception->getTrace();
    $class = $trace[1]['class'];
    if ($class == __CLASS__) {
        $method = $trace[1]['function'];
        $reflect = new ReflectionObject($this);
        $methodList = $reflect->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PROTECTED | ReflectionMethod::IS_PRIVATE);
        foreach ($methodList as $reflectionMethod) {
            if ($method == $reflectionMethod->name) {
                $scopeIsInner = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($scopeIsInner);
```

P.S. I would never use this code in my own application

Comment: Thanks, Don't worry about my design, I know what I am doing. Have over 8 of experience in php. Never needed to check for call scope before, is also more of a curiosity question than a hardcore implementation question. Thought I would ask since there is no documentation on the subject to be found anywhere.